# add audio to my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just cant find the way to add audio to a webpage
basically what i want to do is when the user click the icon the user be able to listen how to pronounce the word.
any suggestion?
i want something like this 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sound_mp3link

but without the player? is it posible just to listen the word(in this case the music) but without the player just listen the music?

Comment: It is possible, but we cannot do all the research for you.

Comment: PLEASE! I beg of you! Stop using W3SCHOOLS! Please look at [this](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, it is using a video, and not an audio element.

Anyway, just use HTML5 audio element, and dont put control attribute

Then, when the user click in the link, just call the play method of the audio element..

Check this example I made now: http://jsfiddle.net/kcqbN/1/

Comment: just one question. is it possible that if you click it while is playing, would be paused or stopped?

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/kcqbN/4/. Also, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Audio

Comment: thank you so much Rafael! you just made my day! :)